# Can I keep my world between Dwarf Fortress versions?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Dwarf Fortress 0.34.08 was just released. When a new (minor) version comes out, can I simply copy my save folder into the new install and keep playing with my original world and fortress, or would I risk some corruption/crash?

Comment: It depends. Toady wanted to make save compatibility a thing, but quite a few releases have broken it. Best to check the description.

Answer (score 3):

the developer has said that [this version is compatible](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=109434.msg3281075#msg3281075)

> As far as I can tell, old saves load up fine and have usable
>   minecart/wheelbarrows, so feel free to move your data/save folder over
>   to the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Even though Toady has stated that the saves are compatible, always keep a backup. Recent updates are consistently unreliable. In general, the best way to see if a save is compatible is to simply try it. Keep in mind, various mods will prevent save compatibility. If you have a mod installed, make sure you install the most recent version of said mod onto the newest version.

One other thing. If you have a save you are concerned about, you may want to wait until a more stable version appears 2-3 weeks from now. There will be plenty of gamebreaking bugs in the first 2 weeks after a major release, and if you don't want to lose progress you should assume the worst.